# Best way to override 1024 process ulimit

Tags: puppet, best-practices, ulimit

On CentOS distros, there is an `/etc/security/limits.d/90-noproc.conf` that sets a process limit for all users:

```
# Default limit for number of user's processes to prevent
# accidental fork bombs.
# See rhbz #432903 for reasoning.

*          soft    nproc     1024
```

I'd like to keep this limit in there, but allow one user to have more than 1024 processes. Because of how the server is puppetized, I'm unable to use the built-in bash `ulimit` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suggest fixing the setting appropriately in Puppet. You can write a line that only applies to that server and adds an entry for your specific user.

The other thing you can do is `chattr +i` (mark as immutable) the file after you make your desired changes. Let's see Puppet change the file then.

The actual resultant file is [/etc/limits.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf)

Comment: Would it be best practice to puppetize my limits.conf? or just add a new file in /etc/security/limits.d/?

Comment: @CamelBlues Just go with limits.d/ since the directory is there. That keeps you from having to fight against the system scripts and write up definitions to turn them off.